# Ctrl + Click in VS Code terminal, show open folder in new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

When I want to Ctrl + Click the error link in terminal VS Code (first project), it showing Open folder in new window (I felt uncomfortable when this happened)

[Open folder in new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgGRw.png)

but when open second project file and ctrl + click the error link in terminal VS Code, it showing Open file in editor

[Open file in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szr9J.png)

I want to set default my terminal, if I ctrl + click on terminal, it showing Open file in editor (second project).

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at your `PROBLEMS` tab, the same errors are there and double clicking will open an editor to that location

Comment: @rioV8 yeah I've looked at Problems tab, but it just showing code spell checker extension for unknown word, when i click one of the unknown word it refer to file that i've clicked before. What I want is when in tab terminal, and then I ctrl + click to the error link, it refer to new tab in that project, not open new window (new vscode). btw thank you for your suggestion

Comment: why don't you use a problem matcher to catch the error messages in the terminal and show them in the PROBLEMS tab

Comment: Problem solved, finally I move the first project folder to folder that the second project exist (same sub folder with second project) and I try to run the first project, and ctrl + click on terminal, if there's an error, the link is show alert or refer to open file in editor not open new window